# Can doxygen move constructors to the top of functions list

Tags: constructor, doxygen, destructor

We use Doxygen to documented our classes.
And have a little problem:
There are many functions in our classes - so we use option SORT_BRIEF_DOCS = NO.
It looks better. But constructors and destructors sorts in list of functions alphabetically too.
I try resolve the problem using  DoxygenLayout.xml file - but unsuccessfully.

Is there way to move constructors and destructors in the top of functions list, despite enabled alphabetically option. Like in detail description.